# Autoit check if Media Encoder converting finished

Tags: encoding, adobe, media, autoit

Is it possible to check in Autoit if the Adobe Media Encoder is finished converting a watch folder from .avi to .mp4?

I looked for a proccess, but could not find something to check if Process exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to wait for the file to be done being made:

```
#include <FileConstants.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

WaitForAdobeMediaFile(@ScriptDir & "\mp4YouAreLookingFor.mp4")
If @error Then
    MsgBox(262160, "Error", "FileExists timeout error.")
Else
    MsgBox(262208, "", "Adobe Media is done making the file.")
EndIf

Func WaitForAdobeMediaFile($sFilePath, $iFileExistsTimeout = 10000, $iWaitForNoMoreChanges = 5000)
    Local $hTimer, $sFileLastModified

    $hTimer = TimerInit()

    ;wait for timeout or for the file exist
    While 1
        ;if file is found
        If FileExists($sFilePath) Then ExitLoop

        ;if the timeout is hit
        If TimerDiff($hTimer) >= $iFileExistsTimeout Then Return SetError(1)
    WEnd

    $hTimer = TimerInit()

    ;gets the date and time that the file was last modified
    $sFileLastModified = FileGetTime($sFilePath, $FT_MODIFIED, 1)
    While 1
        ;reset the last time the file was modified if there was a change
        If $sFileLastModified <> FileGetTime($sFilePath, $FT_MODIFIED, 1) Then
            $hTimer = TimerInit()
            $sFileLastModified = FileGetTime($sFilePath, $FT_MODIFIED, 1)
        Else
            ;if the file has not been modified for the set amount of time
            If TimerDiff($hTimer) >= $iWaitForNoMoreChanges Then ExitLoop
        EndIf
    WEnd
EndFunc   ;==>WaitForAdobeMediaFile
```

You can change the default timeout parameters like so (they are being set in milliseconds).

```
WaitForAdobeMediaFile(@ScriptDir & "\mp4YouAreLookingFor.mp4", 30000, 50000)
```